# Is it better to remove objects form Iterator

Tags: java, performance, iterator, iteration

Is it better to remove the matched objects from iterator so that next iterations become faster.
Ex :

```
for(Favorite favFolder : favFolders) {
    Set<String> rootObjList = new HashSet<String>();
    String favFolderRootUuid = favFolder.getLink();
    Iterator<FavoriteObjectBean> objIter = favObjPage.getBeans().iterator();
    while(objIter.hasNext()) {
            FavoriteObject favObj = objIter.next();
            if(favObj.getFavoriteFolderUuid().equalsIgnoreCase(favFolderRootUuid)) {
                rootObjList.add(favObj.getObjectUuid());
                objIter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

In above code I am removing the objects from iterator if they are matching the criteria.

So my question : is it better to remove so that subsequent iterations are faster as there are lesser number of iterations to perform?

Comment: Subsequent iterations of the outer loop would not become faster, because they use a different `favObjPage.getBeans()` list.

Comment: are you sure you can remove the object from the iterator while it's iterating?

Comment: thats what iterators' special feature, to remove while iterating :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO `Iterator.remove()` is  remove the element  from iterator which is the best way to modify a Collection during iteration because because iterators are fail-fast in java..

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how many beans do you expect to match your criteria.

If it's only one at every inner loop iteration then removing it would hardly make any noticeable difference. On the other hand, if your beans list is large and you do expect a double digit number of beans matching the criteria (which I am assuming can happen only once) then trying to match them again at subsequent iterations of outer loop would be wasting inner loop cycles and hence `Iterator.remove()` should help then.

To conclude, leaving `objIter.remove();` there wouldn't harm and may help depending on the number of matches found. Just make sure any match that you remove should not be eligible for a match again.